Density of states of a Fermi gas for a non symmetric Hamiltonian
I am trying to calculate the density of states for a Hamiltonian of the form
$$ \hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p_x}^2+\hat{p_y}^2+\hat{p_z}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 (\hat{x}^2 + \hat{y}^2) $$
Which is the Hamiltonian of a trapped electron (considered spinless) on the (xOy) plane and free to move on the (Oz) axis.
First, I have considered the case when the oscillator energy is constant, and the particle is free to move on the (Oz) axis (size L very large compared to the dimensions of the system, with BVK conditions) :
$$E = E_0 + \frac{(\hbar k)^2}{2m} $$
Which gives me (with H the Heaviside function) :
$$ \rho(E) = \frac{L\sqrt{m}}{\pi \hbar \sqrt{2}}\frac{H(E-E_0)}{\sqrt{E-E_0}}$$
Now I am stuck because I'd like to find the Fermi level when $E_0$ isn't constant, but instead $E_N = \hbar \omega(1+N)$ with $N = n_x + n_y$
What I'd like to do is to say that, with the level $E_N$
being degenerated $(N+1)$ times :
$$N_e = \int_0^{E_F} \sum_{N = 0} ^\infty (N+1) \rho(E)dE = \int_0^{E_F} \sum_{N = 0} ^\infty (N+1) \frac{L\sqrt{m}}{\pi \hbar \sqrt{2}}\frac{H(E-E_N)}{\sqrt{E-E_N}} $$
$$ N_e = \frac{L\sqrt{m}}{\pi \hbar \sqrt{2}}\sum_{N = 0}^{\frac{E_F}{\hbar \omega} - 1}\int_{\hbar \omega (N+1)}^{E_F}\frac{1}{\sqrt{E-\hbar \omega(N+1)}} = \frac{L\sqrt{2m}}{\pi \hbar }\sum_{N = 0}^{\frac{E_F}{\hbar \omega} - 1} \sqrt{E_F - \hbar \omega(N+1)}$$
Thus I can numerically or grapically compute $E_F$,  but I assume this is wrong because I'd say I am not allowed to sum like I did, as it won't capture the full density.
